Can I join 4x4s to achieve length needed for an open roof pergola?
I'm building an open roof pergola with dressed 4x4, planning on using cedar. Only issue is local lumber yards can only provide 12 ft lengths, and I need 14 ft for the widest span. I was already planning on 45 degree braces to accommodate the long span - question is can I join shorter boards to accomplish the needed length? Initial thought was to put the joints over where the braces will sit. I would join them using an appropriately sized flat strap.
There's nothing on top of the pergola, so it's just supporting itself and small critters.


It probably will work with no load on it, but the joints have to be cut exactly to blend in.  Have you asked about custom orders?  My lumber yard only stocked 16ft 2x10s, but needed 20ft.  they custom ordered the length for me.

I did ask - they called the mill and can only get 12 ft. It's eastern white cedar, so not sure if it's a little harder to source longer 4x4 boards. Joints are going to have straps over them, so it's not like it'll be hidden. I'll call around to a few more places, but I'm not optimistic.

Is there a reason you want to use 4x4?

Sure, there are any number of joints that would do the job. A half-lap comes to mind.
It's not a matter of procurement or fabrication, though. That's too long a span. Even an unladen 4x4 with an 11 foot span will sag. There's a reason you don't see them used horizontally in other designs.
Consider using 2x8. It amounts to roughly the same volume of wood, but it's shaped properly to span your distance. It also looks much more appropriate to folks with some architectural understanding. 4x4s belong around flower beds, supported by the ground, if used horizontally.

Is there a reference for an acceptable span of unladen 4x4? Certainly 5 ft would work. As would 6. Where’s the cutoff? Are the numbers from the sagulator (https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) accurate if I use dimensional lumber measurements?

What's acceptable in a case like this is wildly subjective. I'm speaking from experience (in both construction and demolition). I'm sharing facts, not judgement. It'll sag. You decide whether that's ok.

Often 4x4s are cut out of the very center of smaller trees with the pith running right thru the center. They're especially prone to bending/warping/twisting even without being hung horizontally.
